# Error: arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _Z9rtx_alloc8rtx_code

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack

I build image for bbb refer to this guide
https://forum.digikey.com/t/debian-getting-started-with-the-beaglebone-black/12967

After setup image done, I try to make a kernel module hello_module.c and Makefile but I have a error when run make:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/thanh/work/bbb/bb-kernel/KERNEL'
  CC [M]  /home/thanh/work/bbb/kernelspace/hello_module.o
cc1: error: cannot load plugin ./scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so
   ./scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _Z9rtx_alloc8rtx_code
```

Content of Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello_module.o
 
CROSS=/home/thanh/work/bbb/gcc-linaro-6.5.0-2018.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
KERNEL=/home/thanh/work/bbb/bb-kernel/KERNEL/
all:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) clean
```

How to I resolve this error? Please help me, thanks

Resolve this error.

Comment: @stark It's not about kernel. It is a gcc error message, it can't load its plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is an incompatibility between the native host compiler that is used to build gcc plugin(s), and the cross-compiler that is used to compile kernel/drivers.

Try to disable plugin use by this line in BBB defconfig

```
# CONFIG_GCC_PLUGINS is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong compiler.

obj-m += hello_module.o

CROSS=/home/thanh/work/bbb/bb-kernel/dl/gcc-8.5.0-nolibc/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-
KERNEL=/home/thanh/work/bbb/bb-kernel/KERNEL/
all:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS} -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C ${KERNEL} M=$(PWD) clean